# ubuntu: Почему не устанавливается xdebug?

Tags: php, ubuntu, отладка, xdebug, remote-debugging

уважаемые знатоки ubuntu!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Вывожу с помощью команды php -i включенный сейчас дистрибутив php. Показывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме 8.0 у меня есть на wsl 2 8.1.

ставлю xedbug командами

sudo apt update

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install php-xdebug

как ни странно, в директории etc - php - php8.0, в папке mods-available не появляется файла xdebug.ini и вообще никаких следов, что что-либо установилось..

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `sudo apt install php8.1-xdebug` возможно поможет

Comment: @Jour, но если у меня сейчас на сервере установлен php 8.0.23, то это значит, что у меня дистрибутив 8.0 работает, а не 8.1 правильно?

Comment: да, `php8.0-xdebug` попробуйте) как называется у вас папка в `/etc/php*`

Comment: Сработало, благодарю за совет!